# swiftui charts and axis labels

Tags: swift, charts

[image]not very experienced with swift but Im messing around with charts. I have some data that I would like to plot and it seems that swift will not mark the x and y axis' with anything that has two or more digits.  from the code you can see I have tried a few different things but nothing seems to work.  I would like to have the scale show up on both the x and y axis according to xValues and yValues.  any help is appreciated. as you can see I have commented out some code as I have tried to solve this.

```
    struct GraphView: View {
    
    @StateObject var vm: DownloadWithEscapingViewModel = DownloadWithEscapingViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        
        let data: [CombinedEspData] = vm.sortedEspArray
        let xMin = Double(data.first?.time ?? 0) / 3600
        //        let xMinRound = round(1000 * xMin) / 1000
        let xMax = Double(data.last?.time ?? 0) / 3600
        //        let xMaxRound = round(1000 * xMax) / 1000
        let yMin = data.first?.value ?? 0
        let yMax = data.last?.value ?? 0
        //        let xDiff = (xMax - xMin)
        //        let yDiff = (yMax - yMin)
        let xValues = stride(from: xMin, to: xMax, by: 0.5).map {$0}
        let yValues = stride(from: yMin, to: yMax, by: 5).map {$0}
        
        VStack {
            GeometryReader { geometry in
                Chart(vm.sortedEspArray){ data in
                    LineMark (x: .value("Time", Double(data.time) / 3600),
                              y: .value("Value", data.value)
                    )
                    .foregroundStyle(Color(.red))
                    //.lineStyle(StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 5, lineCap: .round , dash: [10]))
                }
                .padding()
                .frame(width: geometry.size.width, height: geometry.size.height)
                .chartXScale(domain: xMin...xMax)
                .chartYScale(domain: yMin...yMax)
                .chartXAxis{
                    AxisMarks(position: .bottom, values: xValues)
                }
                .chartYAxis{
                    AxisMarks(position: .leading, values: yValues)
                }
                .onAppear(perform: {
                    vm.getPosts()
                })
            }
            .frame(height: 300)
            //            Text("\(data.first!.time)")
            Text("x min - \(xMin)")
            Text("x max - \(xMax)")
            Text("y min - \(yMin)")
            Text("y max - \(yMax)")
            Spacer()
        }
    }
    
}

struct SwiftUIView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        GraphView()
    }
}
```